# Sql advanced searching

Tags: sql, search, expression

I'm trying to create a search engine for e-shop and I want make this:

If the client writes e.x galaxy white in the search bar I want to execute a sql query that matches that string with the products not only the ones with a title like galaxy white s3 but also with titles like galaxy s3 white 16 gb.

Is that possible?

Comment: Short answer - yes, it's possible. If you are  looking for out of box solution, it depends on RDMS you are using(SQLServer, Oracle, MySql, Postgres, etc).

Comment: Deleted your repeated paragraph

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement a search by looking at the distance between the searched keywords and the titles in the database. [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm is a good distance algorithm.

**UPDATE:** For the subword string search

Levenshtein is good for mispellings. In addition to that you can split the string into words and then make a Naïve string search for your words. Then you can union the results with Levenshtein results.

In e.g., if user searches for "galaxy white s4";

You can split this string into three words:

```
galaxy
white
s4
```

Then for each word, you can make a Naïve string search in the titles such as :

```
SELECT * FROM Titles 
WHERE 
Titles LIKE '%galaxy%' OR 
Titles LIKE '%white%' OR
Titles LIKE '%s4%'
```

Up to now, this should solve your problem. But I have a few suggestions!

Michal Borek's suggestion for having synonyms is a great idea. It would improve your results. Also I would suggest using tags, for example if user searches for an attribute say bluetooth, you may want to return the devices with bluetooth support.

Comment: I tried Levenshtein but i don't think is very useful.If the user puts galaxy white i want to show him all the products with titles that contains galaxy and white.Levenshtein only returns the diffrence of the strings

Comment: Oh ok.I thought it too, to split up the string but in a case of an input like game of thrones season 3 i got 5 strings and its a very long query.

Comment: Yes, but query length is rarely an issue. What matters is cost of the query. Besides, there are several other algorithms. But we can only suggest based on the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

To be more accurate it may be needed to provide "similar phrases" (synonyms). Because e.g. you're searching for a phone on Windows Phone 8, and you may just type "WP8", Levenshtein distance won't solve that problem.

Comment: +1 for synonyms. Since the question didn't mention synonyms I suggested Levenshtein of the top of my head.

Comment: You're right, your answer is perfectly fine, although my answer was rather an advice.